# Selecting Multiple Nodes on the Same Level w/ LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to select multiple nodes in one query.

My XML looks like

```
<View Id="View#1">
    <Node1 DefinitionId="DefinitionId1">
        // ...
    </Node1>
</View>
<View Id="View#2">
    <Node2 DefinitionId="DefinitionId2">
        // ...
    </Node2>
</View>
<View Id="View#3">
    <Node3 DefinitionId="DefinitionId3">
        // ...
    </Node3>
</View>
```

I'm currently have the XML document loaded through XDocument.Load and I am parsing the resultant XML through LINQ to XML.

I'm basically trying to get all of the definition id's of all the node types into a single string collection.

My current code looks like this

```
IList<string> node1Ids = _xmlFile
    .Descendants("Node1")
    .Select(n => n.Attribute("DefinitionId").Value).ToList();

IList<string> node2Ids = _xmlFile
    .Descendants("Node2")
    .Select(n => n.Attribute("DefinitionId").Value).ToList();
```

Is there any way of putting all of this into one query such as

```
IList<string> nodeIds = _xmlFile
    .Descendants("Node1")
    .Descendants("Node2")
    .Descendants("Node3")
    .Select(n => n.Attribute("DefinitionId").Value).ToList();
```

Obviously the above does not work but I'm wondering if there is an equivalent to allow me to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `_xmlFile.Descendants("View").Elements().Attributes("DefinitionId").Select(a => a.Value).ToList()`. That assumes that you are looking for the `DefinitionId` attributes of all child elements of all `View` elements. Or you need something like `Descendants().Where(d => d.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("Node")).Attributes("DefinitionId").Select(a => a.Value).ToList()`.

Answer (score 1):

You may try below:

```
IList<string> nodeIds = _xmlFile
    .Descendants().Where( d => d.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("Node") )
    .Select(n => n.Attribute("DefinitionId").Value).ToList();
```